# How can I create the folder using MakeFile?

Tags: macos, makefile, terminal, clion

I need to create folder (called obj/) using Makefile and put there the result program of makefile. How can i do this?

```
TARGET = lab-01_makefile
CC = gcc

PREF_SRC = ./src/
PREF_OBJ = ./obj/

SRC = $(wildcard $(PREF_SRC)*.c)
OBJ = $(patsubst $(PREF_SRC)%.c, $(PREF_OBJ)%.o, $(SRC))

$(TARGET) : $(OBJ)
   $(CC) $(OBJ) -I include -o $(TARGET)

$(PREF_OBJ)%.o : $(PREF_SRC)%.c
   $(CC) -c $< -I include -o $@

clean :
   rm $(TARGET) $(PREF_OBJ)*.o
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just add a `mkdir` to your recipe?

```
$(TARGET) : $(OBJ)
        @mkdir -p $(@D)
        $(CC) $(OBJ) -I include -o $(TARGET)

$(PREF_OBJ)%.o : $(PREF_SRC)%.c
        @mkdir -p $(@D)
        $(CC) -c $< -I include -o $@
```

If you don't want to do that you could add it as an immediately expanded shell function invocation:

```
__ := $(shell mkdir -p $(PREF_OBJ))
```

If you don't like any of those you could use an order-only prerequisite on all targets that might want to use it:

```
$(TARGET) : $(OBJ) | $(PREF_OBJ)
        $(CC) $(OBJ) -I include -o $(TARGET)

$(PREF_OBJ)%.o : $(PREF_SRC)%.c | $(PREF_OBJ
        $(CC) -c $< -I include -o $@

$(PREF_OBJ):
        @mkdir -p $@
```